# Creating a Pandas DataFrame from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have the following dataset: There are 2 columns SubmittedAt and values:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBEXx.png)

I want to take the list of dictionaries in the values column and create a DataFrame as below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ABDO.png)

Currently, I'm using a 'for' loop to unpack the list of dictionaries. In the below code, I'm creating a list of dates from the first dataset and then using a for loop to add the rest of the data in the list as columns.

```
dates = []

for i in df1['submittedAt']:
    dates.append(i)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['name','value'])

i = 0
for dict_val in df1['values']:
    df2 = df2.append({'submittedAt': dates[i]}, ignore_index=True)
    for single_dict in dict_val:
        df2 = df2.append(single_dict , ignore_index=True)
    i = i+1
```

The for loop is good for a small set of data, but with a larger set of data, it takes more than an hour to run. I'm still new to python, please provide some suggestions which will reduce the time it takes to run my code.

Also, is it possible to unpack the list and create a DataFrame with the below structure?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4KgI.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert dictionary items to rows of pandas data frame where keys are tuples and values are integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53063664/convert-dictionary-items-to-rows-of-pandas-data-frame-where-keys-are-tuples-and)

Comment: Hi Danny, this is a new method. I will try it with my data and see if it works. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

list_dict=[{'name': 'first_name', 'value': 'abc'}, {'name': 'last_name', 'value': 'xyz'}, {'name': 'email', 'value': 'abc@gmail.com'}]
df=pd.DataFrame(list_dict)
```

ouput

```
    name        value
0   first_name  abc
1   last_name   xyz
2   email       abc@gmail.com
```

Comment: Hi Lokeshwar, There are multiple rows of list of dictionaries, so I need to access them one by one. I also have another column called submitted at which needs to be added to the dataframe